# Locate camera, Roblox Studio, Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

There exist any form to know the location of the camera? in coordinates

I thought that in the object "player" exist a variable where it says, but no.

Comment: See [game.workspace.CurrentCamera](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Workspace/CurrentCamera) and [camera.CFrame](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Camera/CFrame)

Answer (score 0):

```
local cam = game.Workspace.Camera
print(cam.CFrame.Position)
```

This code prints the Vector3 Position of the camera but always use this in local script.